# Kubernetes how to use Redis host and port in microservices without using environment variables

Tags: redis, dns, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

After installing Redis using Helm chart, how do I use Hedis in our microservices using DNS?

I tried using environmental variables. But I have no idea how to do using DNS, because it expects host and port.

Comment: What do you mean under `microservices using DNS`?

Comment: let me give an example. For Redis, after deploying using helm charts, if we want to use that host and port in java microservice (basically in code) how to use that and it will have master and slave. which dns name to use. I am new to kubernetes, sorry if i am being wrong